# Installing a Python module in an intranet

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to install Python library requirements for a project in a server on our company's intranet. However, because of this any external access is blocked and I cannot download any libraries that are needed. We have set up our internal mirror site for 'official' packages that can be downloaded and installed as long as their dependencies don't leave internal network.
Here's an error I'm getting when trying to install particular 'ibm_db' package:

```
    Downloading https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/ntx64_odbc_cli.zip
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "d:\app\python\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 1318, in do_open
        encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
      File "d:\app\python\Lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
        self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
      File "d:\app\python\Lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
        self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "d:\app\python\Lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
        self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "d:\app\python\Lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
        self.send(msg)
      File "d:\app\python\Lib\http\client.py", line 964, in send
        self.connect()
      File "d:\app\python\Lib\http\client.py", line 1392, in connect
        super().connect()
      File "d:\app\python\Lib\http\client.py", line 936, in connect
        (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
      File "d:\app\python\Lib\socket.py", line 704, in create_connection
        for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
      File "d:\app\python\Lib\socket.py", line 743, in getaddrinfo
        for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Is there a way to work-around this? Like move virtual environment from my local workstation to the server? Or download all required files and install them in offline mode?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by doing this workaround:

```
1. Installed ibm_db in my local virtual environment using easy_install
2. Used 'wheel convert' to create an .whl file from installed folder
3. Copied .whl file to the server and used its 'pip' to install the wheel file
4. No issues were observed.
```